# Does C#/.NET have a built-in "VersionNumber" class?

Tags: c#, .net, versioning

I need to keep track of an arbitrary version number in my C# application, which has the form `M+.m+.b+`, where `M` is "Major", `m` is "minor", `b` is "build", and `+` indicates that the version number is not restricted to one digit per number.

Is there a built-in class that basically just holds 3 or 4 (the 4th would be the revision number) `int`s and provides some convenient comparison functions, or do I need to write my own? I imagine it would look something like this:

```
class VersionNumber
{
    public int Major;
    public int Minor;
    public int Build;
    public int Revision;

    static public VersionNumber operator >(VersionNumber number)
    {
        // Comparison function here.
    }

    // Other comparison functions and whatnot here.
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the [Version Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Version(v=vs.110).aspx) I think. Specifically the [Revision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision(v=vs.110).aspx) property and the [Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.build(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Check this: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` which returns a version object.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks you two. I'd accept either of these comments as answers if you posted them as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this MSDN Link: [Version Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx). The type `System.Version` comes with these properties:

- Build
- Major
- MajorRevision
- Minor
- MinorRevision
- Revision